# Простой слайдер на js

Tags: javascript

Пробую сделать простой слайдер на js с точками, но что-то не работает. Подскажите, где ошибка в js :

```
function action1(){
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    img1.style.display = "block";

}
function action2(){
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
    img2.style.display = "block";

}
function action3(){
    var img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
    img3.style.display = "block";

}
```

Слайдер по ссылке : [Простой слайдер на js](https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/LjPVym)

Comment: Это конечно похвально, изобретать свои решения, но почему вы просто не хотите воспользоваться готовым, легковесным решением?Например: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: Или ещё есть очень неплохой слайдер slick: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Не люблю, когда не понимаю. Делаю сам слайдер, чтобы понять принцип его действия)))

Comment: Вам просто нужно играться с свойством `display:none` и `display:block`, когда жмете на конкретный слайд - остальные получают `display:none`, конкретный получает `display:block`, это если "на пальцах".

Comment: @Klimenkomud, зачем сразу display? почему не подойдут например opacity/transform/visibility/position absolute?

Comment: @NeedHate Ну это пожалуй самый простой способ, можно выставлять слайды и абсолютом, пихать не нужные слайды за края экрана, а нужный слайд - в центре блока, даже с `position:relative;`. Это уже малость потяжелее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjbxGV

```js
function action1() {
    hideAll();
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    img1.style.display = "block";
}

function action2(){
    hideAll();
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
    img2.style.display = "block";
}

function action3(){
    hideAll();
    var img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
    img3.style.display = "block";
}

function hideAll() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('#polosa>img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.slider {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#polosa {
    height: 128px;  
    display: block;
}
#polosa img {
    display: none;
}
.buttons {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 128px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.buttons .button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div id="polosa">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2110/64/Facebook-01-128.png" id="img1">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-vol-2-1/200/4-128.png" id="img2">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-icon/112/vk-128.png" id="img3">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button" onclick="action1()"></div>
    <div class="button" onclick="action2()"></div>
    <div class="button" onclick="action3()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял вы хотите по нажатию на точку переключать изображение.
Вам нужно открыть ( display: block; ) #polosa и скрыть все изображения внутри( #polosa img { display: none; } ).
А по нажатию на точку, кроме открытия img еще и закрывать все остальные открытые ранее.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Индекс слайда по умолчанию */
const slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

/* Функция увеличивает индекс на 1, показывает следующй слайд*/
function plusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

/* Функция уменьшяет индекс на 1, показывает предыдущий слайд*/
function minusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);  
}

/* Устанавливает текущий слайд */
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

/* Основная функция слайдера */
function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dots_item");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Более подробную информацию по ссылке
http://lantana-studio.ru/howto/simpleslider/